# opencsv content - values after comma

Tags: java, excel, csv, opencsv

I am using Java and opencsv(2.3) to create csv files.

It is created properly. But when I am opening the file I see all the data appears in single column.

In order to align the values into separate columns

1.I select "Text to Columns" in data tab of excel

2.And I select Delimiter as ";"

3. I see all the values are splitted into separte columns properly but the values after comma are getting vanished

**CSVWriter I use to create CSV files:**

```
   File file = new File(fileName);
   CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true), ';');
   String[] col= new String[4];

   for(Customer c : CustomerList) {
         col[0] = c.getCustomerName();
         col[1] = c.getCustomerId();
         col[2] = c.getCustomerBirthDate();
         col[3] = c.getRegFee(); /** 145,65**/
         col[4] = c.getRegPlace();
         writer.writeNext(col);
   }

   writer.close();
```

**CSV File - Actual content:**

```
"Micky";"1";"19901220";"455,56";"Place1"

"Grace";"2";"19901231";"465,87";"Place2"
```

**CSV File - while opening using excel:**

```
   "Micky";"1";"19901220";"455" // , 56 and Place1 are vanished

   "Grace";"2";"19901231";"465" // , 87 and Place2 are vanished
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is to do with the way you're importing it to Excel.

Using your sample above, I've created a CSV file and opened it in Notepad to verify the content.

[image]

If you double-click a CSV file (and have Excel associated with that file type) it will open in Excel and it looks like Excel is attempting to use the comma as a delimiter by default. It displays the data across 2 columns.

[image]

If you open Excel, then import the CSV file you can tell Excel that your file is delimited and that the semi-colon is the delimiter. Import using the From Text menu item from the Data tab:

[image]

It will then display correctly:

[image]

Comment: No I select semi-colon as a delimiter, can it be linked with number format, I mean thousand and decimal separator??

Comment: @AlagammalP I don't think so. I configured Excel to use a full-stop as the thousand separator and a comma as a decimal separator.  I still had the same result as in the screenshot above.